# Comparing utf-8 strings in java

Tags: java, unicode

In my java program, I am retrieving some data from xml. This xml has few international characters and is encoded in utf8. Now I read this xml using xml parser. Once I retrieve a particular international string from xml parser, I need to compare it with set of predefined strings. Problem is when I use string.equals on internatinal string comparison fails.

How to compare strings with international strings in java ? I am using SAXParser & XMLReader to read strings from xml.

Here's the line that compares strings

```
 String country;
 country = getXMLNodeString();

 if(country.equals("Côte d'Ivoire"))
 {    

 } 

  getXMLNodeString()
  {

  /* Get a SAXParser from the SAXPArserFactory. */  
        SAXParserFactory spf = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
        SAXParser sp = spf.newSAXParser();

        /* Get the XMLReader of the SAXParser we created. */
        XMLReader xr = sp.getXMLReader();
        /* Create a new ContentHandler and apply it to the XML-Reader*/
        XmlParser xmlParser = new XmlParser();  //my class to parse xml
        xr.setContentHandler(xmlParser);  

        /* Parse the xml-data from our URL. */
        xr.parse(new InputSource(url.openStream()));
        /* Parsing has finished. */


       //return string here
  }
```

Comment: Do `System.out.println(country)` to a console supporting `UTF-8` (if you're using Eclipse, you can configure console encoding by *Window > Preferences > General > Workspace > Text File Encoding*) and paste it here. Note: when you say "international characters" you actually mean to say ["unicode characters"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode).

Comment: How would it help for comparison ??

Comment: No error. But comparison fails and control does not enter if.

Comment: What do you get if you System.out.println(country)?

Comment: Decoded Unicode strings should be compared using the Unicode Collation Algorithm.  Otherwise you will get screwed up by things like normalization.  But it smells like you are unclear on encodings.

Answer (score 7):

Java stores `String`s internally as an array of `char`s, which are 16 bit unsigned values. This was based on an earlier Unicode standard that supported 64K characters.

Your String constant `"Côte d'Ivoire"` is in this format. If your character encoding on your XML document is correct then the `String` read from there will also be in the correct format. So possible errors are:

1. The XML document doesn't declare a character encoding;
2. The declared character encoding does not match the actual character encoding used.

Perhaps the XML string is being treated as US-ASCII instead of UTF-8. I would output both and eyeball them. If they look the same, compare them character by character to see where teh comparison fails. You may also want to compare the UTF8 encoding of your constant `String` to what's in the XML document:

```
byte[] bytes = "Côte d'Ivoire".getBytes("UTF-8");
```

It gets more complicated when you start getting into "supplementary characters". These are characters beyond the originally intended 64K ("code points" in Unicode parlance). See [Supplementary Characters in the Java Platform](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Intl/Supplementary/). This isn't an issue with any of the characters you're using but it's worth noting for completeness.

Comment: Correct! My xml document has no tag specifying character encoding.
What is default character encoding assumed ?

Comment: @cppdev but what you need to do is see where the comparison fails. Compare character by character and byte by byte to see where the difference lies. From there you/we should be able to figure out the why.

Comment: @cppdev What is `getXMLNodeString()`? Does it return a `String` or something else? Possibly a text node? That's not a standard function. Maybe you should post the code to that.

Comment: it gets *even more* complicated when when you take into account composed and decomposed forms of accented characters and ligatures.

Comment: The default encoding for XML is UTF-8 as is specified here: http://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#charencoding

Comment: Leave it to W3C to make the wording unreadable :) "it is a fatal error [..] for an entity which begins with neither a Byte Order Mark nor an encoding declaration to use an encoding other than UTF-8. Note that since ASCII is a subset of UTF-8, ordinary ASCII entities do not strictly need an encoding declaration."

Comment: In other words: If there is no encoding declared, the encoding MUST be UTF-8 (or ASCII, which is a subset of UTF-8) or else it is considered an error.

Answer (score 3):

Since you're comparing with a string literal, you need to make sure that you're saving your source file in the same encoding that `javac` is expecting.  You can also specify what encoding your source files are in with the `-encoding` argument to `javac`.

That seems like the most likely "gotcha" in this scenario.

Note that I'm talking about the encoding of your Java source code, not the XML document.

Comment: Good point, this may indeed bite you! Eclipse will actually save .java files in a platform-specific (e.g. ISO-8859-1) format by default! I described how to change that on my blog: http://stijndewitt.wordpress.com/2010/05/05/unicode-utf-8-in-eclipse-java/

Answer (score 2):

Java strings are always UTF-16.  Your XML parser should be converting the file's UTF-8 characters into UTF-16 while reading, and your own strings are already UTF-16 in memory, so you can compare them with an ordinary `equals()` call.  If they aren't comparing equal when you think they should, the problem is likely something else.

Answer (score 0):

If your XML file is tagged as  and the text file is saved as an actual UTF-8 file you can use contentEquals(literal or string) like so:

```
if (strMyvalue.contentEquals("Côte d'Ivoire") {
    // execute
}
```

Comment: No, you can’t do `contentEquals` on Unicode strings and expect sane results. They may have the same text but not be bitwise equivalent. You have forgotten about normalization, amongst other things. Java isn’t good with Unicode, because it has no proper Unicode String class.  Consider `Co\x{302}te d\x{2019}Ivoire` and `C\x{F4}te d\x{2019}Ivoire`, not to mention also `C\x{F4}te d'Ivoire`.  Those all have the same letters, and the first pair are even canonically equivalent. Don’t trust non-text approaches to Unicode text like you have suggested.